# Which “square filter” brand does this hood belong to?

Tags: filters, lens-hood, cokin

I’ve bought this hood in a flea market some time ago thinking it’s a Cokin one but actually it’s not compatible. Notice the different notches. So I wonder what it is, so maybe I could pass it on when I know...

[image: filter hood]

Answer (score 1):

To me, that looks like a Cokin brand filter hood.

Comment: However the notches are different and it’s not stackable.